# Entering a folder with a template path - C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, filesystems, filepath, glob

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2017 Professional and MFC

---

I am working on a project which has a function that collects file paths (like `C:/foo1/foo2/foo3.txt`) as `string`s, if a file with that path exists (found using the `filesystem` [library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)).

At first this looks straightforward until I see that the file paths often are simply (for lack of a better word) *templates*.

My program is given a template file path such as this:
`C:/User/Documents/%A/%B.txt`, where `%A` represents a year (which my program has a range for and iterates through each year, comparing to the template folder) and %B is the month, again iterating.

It only gets more complicated, because we now add two more template symbols: `*` and `?`.
For example:
`C:/User/Documents/*_%A_??_*/%B_*.txt`.

Here, `*` represents 0 or more characters and `?` represents one character.
So in the example, a filepath like: `C:/User/Documents/smile_2022_A1_/07_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP.txt` should be found and saved as a `string`.

I am able to separate the file path via tokenization, meaning I already have a function that collects a `vector` filled with, say, `C:`, `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3.txt`. With this I can iterate through the `vector` either with a loop or recursively enter a folder until I either:

1. reach a deadend (aka the folder or file does not exist)
2. reach the file I want and save its entire path as a `string`

One thought I have come up with is look for `_` symbols and separate the folder or file name with those but this gets countered by:

1. if the `*` or `?` contain a `_`
2. if the folder or file name simply do not contain `_`

The solution I am looking for ideally does not utilize `regex`. However, if that is the only solution (obviously I do not want to recreate `regex`), please advise me on how I can use it on varying path complexities, as my function should allow for both regular folder paths without template symbols and those with them.

The reason I say no `regex` is because from my understanding, it is a little more strict when it comes to comparing a file. It expects the `string` to be written in a certain generic but consistent way. However, in my case I cannot expect a user to name their folders in a consistent manner...

Comment: If you already have the template path tokenized, have you considered just creating a `TokenMatcher`-like class that evaluates for each token that it matches the template? If you create a vector of these (1 per token), then when walking all files in a directory, just check that each matcher evaluates `true` for a given path to find a file path that satisfies the template

Comment: @Human-Compiler do you have a source on this ? my first time using tokens and I tokenized the string very simply by separating by the char ```\```

Comment: @franji1 thank you I will test this out right now and update

Comment: @franji1, I doubt if these APIs will work if they contain wildcards in the directory path, I think only the filename part can contain wildcards. The application should check for the first wildcard, and if this is contained in the directory path, it should be searched with FindFirstFile/FindNextFile (searching for directories only), and for each directory found call the algorithm recursively (for the rest of the string).

Comment: I wonder why you're preemptively rejecting the obvious solution. You have a [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator), a [`directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), and [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). You don't need anything else to produce a [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). If VS2017 didn't receive C++20 support you can leave out the latter, and go for a more tedious interface.

Comment: mhmm, I understand that, I am simply asking if there is another solution to it .. @IInspectable

Comment: @franji1 tested this out, thank you thank you it is working beautifully at least with the initial testing !! very big thank you I have been working on this part of a function for a week already haha <3 ( if you would like to add it as an answer, add it and I will accept it as correct because it is ! )

Comment: Sure, there is. It's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73197864/1889329) you've accepted. You might not know, or care, but that just introduced another instance of the [Y2K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) problem. You've ultimately limited your search space prior to evaluating the predicate.

Comment: could you elaborate ? also what do you mean by evaluating the predicate ? also something that is program specific is that I will be searching in a certain time frame, so I would not have to worry about 1900s or 2100s if that is what you mean

Comment: The program stops operating properly as soon as a data point is introduced that falls outside the range 1900-2100. Software is expensive and has a tendency to be in operation way beyond its intended life span. Besides that, the approach is inherently inefficient: You're enumerating all patterns, and for each pattern you are hitting the disk. That's 2400 patterns (200 years with 12 months each). Enumerating all files *once*, and matching the path names against a pattern causes far less I/O traffic. I/O is expensive.

Comment: I see thank you for the explanation; that makes sense and is something I considered but to things more complicated, the files I am looking for can be dated down to the second, and because of this I am iterating through each second of a certain time frame. generally the time frame will not be more than an hour but of course the user could choose something enormous if they did want to, I considered implementing something that could be more general and less resource intensive, but I could not think of the logic needed to program it coherently @IInspectable , again I appreciate the response :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you replace YOUR env variables (%A, %B, etc.), then `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` API calls support wild cards.

Comment: after some quick preliminary testing, this is working exactly as desired, will update if any changes, thank you again :)

Comment: a follow-up question - if either of the ```FindFirstFile``` does not succeed, do I still call the ```FindClose``` function to close the handle ? @franji1

Comment: From the online documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea)... "If the function fails or fails to locate files from the search string in the lpFileName parameter, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and the contents of lpFindFileData are indeterminate."  Hence, you should NOT call `FindClose` w/INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.  I would also assume a NULL/0 value is failure also, so don't call `FindClose` w/0.

Comment: The online topics point to an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Thank you and one last question - do you know what to do if ```FindClose``` fails ? it returns a bool, what should I do if it returns 0 (fail)

Comment: [Clean-up functions can't fail because, well, how do you clean up from a failed clean-up?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080107-00/?p=23913) If `FindClose` fails then it does so due to a bug in your program. You can log the error, but beyond that there's not much you can do. [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) is a powerful tool in preventing those bugs. Create a wrapper around the `HANDLE`, initialize it from the c'tor or throw if it's `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. If you throw, the d'tor won't run, cutting out this failure mode altogether.